# Login not working with proper username

Tags: iphone, authentication, nsurlconnection

I called server url  database connection for identify username and password. I used NSURL. If i enter wrong username and password it displays connection sucessfully in NSLog. If i enter correct username and password it displays connection successfully. If i nothing enter in username and password UITextField then click the login button it displays connection successfully. I need to work for only correct username and password

code:

```
-(void)login:(id)sender{


    NSString *uname=usrname.text;
    NSString *pword=password.text;    

    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver.net/projects/mobile/database_connection.php?name=%@&password=%@",uname, pword]]; //Here you place your URL Link


    NSLog(@"url is %@",theURL);

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    if (connection) {
        NSLog(@"connection successful");

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Failed");
    }


}


-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    //NSLog(@"Did Receive Data %@", data);
    [receiveData appendData:data];

}
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

    [receiveData setLength:0];

}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSLog(@"recieved data lenght is %d", [receiveData length]);

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@" , error);
}


// Implement TextField delegate

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


-(void)touchesBegan :(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: You only check whether the `NSURLConnection` is create not the response of the HTTP call.

Comment: How can i do for HTTP call?

Comment: at connectionDidFinishLoading method log your responce data not it's length and put condition that don't allow user to pass blank username and password to webservice

Comment: It's now only for blank username. It also allowing wrong username

Comment: If i enter blank i got null username password. url ishttp://server.net/projects/mobile/database_connection.php?name=(null)&password=(null)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to prevent the user enter blank password and username.

You can have a check in your login method before creating NSURLConnection

```
-(void)login:(id)sender
{
    NSString *uname=usrname.text;
    NSString *pword=password.text;    
    if([uname length]>0 && [pword length]>0)
    {
           NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver.net/projects/mobile/database_connection.php?name=%@&password=%@",uname, pword]]; //Here you place your URL Link

           NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
           NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
           if (connection) {
               NSLog(@"connection successful");
           }
           else {
               NSLog(@"Failed");
           }
    }
}
```

Don't create the `NSURLConnection` object if the user has not enter any in username and password.

The best way is to disable the login button until the user enter username and password.

**EDIT:**

Start the NSURLConnection using `[connection start]`.

Go through [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation, you will understand better.

Comment: It's working for only user not enter username. How to use incorrect username & password

Comment: when i run my server url in browser it nothing displays. Is it need to display username and password code?

Comment: I didn't understand. Where to write?

Comment: is you delegate methods are getting called ??

Comment: check what response you are getting in `didReceiveResponse`

Comment: Im getting response is Did Receive Response <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x75917b0>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36900/discussion-between-prasad-devadiga-and-user2674668)